# How do I use this Digital Temperature Controller?

Tags: equipment, fermentation-temperature

For my birthday, I asked my sister for a Digital Temperature Controller. Rather than buy [the one from Norther Brewer](http://www.northernbrewer.com/brewing/brewing-equipment/fermenting-equipment/fermentation-temperature-control/johnson-controls-a419-digital-temp-controller.html), I found what I thought was a better deal from Pex Supplies. However, it looks like the one I got isn't exactly the same.

What I thought I was getting was the ability to plug a freezer into the controller, and the controller into an outlet. However, the one I got is quite confusing. Maybe it is that, just more work on my end? Is it easy to attach a power cord to this? Electrician noob I am.

Anyway, here are some pictures of the one I got. The description of the one I got can be seen [here](http://www.pexsupply.com/Johnson-Controls-A419GBF-1C-Single-Stage-Digital-Temperature-Control-24v-SPDT).

[image: Digital Temperature Controller]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this diagram on a [thread on Northern Brewer](http://forum.northernbrewer.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=21395&start=0). Helps immensely for the electrician-impaired:
[image: A419 Diagram]
<sub>(source: [danmerk.com](http://www.danmerk.com/a419_dwg.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Downvoted because the OP's controller take 24v, not 120. For OP to follow this suggestion would be dangerous.

Comment: @Frazbro If it helps, I got it to work and didn't die, though I can't recall anything about it since the (I believe I sold it in 2011).

Comment: Good news, I hadn't realised this was such an old post - it was right at the top of my feed...

Answer (score 2):

My big concern is that it is expecting 24vac input to power the device and power the temperature control.  if that's the case,  I think you got the wrong one.

It looks to be true:  "The A419 controls are available in 24 VAC or 120/240 VAC powered models."

Comment: OPPS. I think you got the wrong one too. Should have gotten the 120VAC.

Comment: There is a Spec sheet on that website at the bottom.  It contains a wiring diagram.  You need 120VAC (or 110VAC doesn't make a difference)

Comment: Use a wire nut to connect the grounds (green) when you get the correct controller. Or just don't cut it when you attach the extension cord.

Comment: Jeff and Tim are right, that's the wrong unit.

Answer (score 0):

take an extension cord, cut it in half put the male side into the the ac input and put the femails side in the C (Common) and NO (Normally Open) terminals.

I'd expect that to "close" the circuit when the temperature controller needs to heat, or cool, what ever it's set to do.

If it works backwards, move it over to the NC but I don't expect that's the right terminal

oh and for the temperature probe that does in the terminal at the top. but the pic isn't clear for me to see exactly how.

Comment: Do not do this, OP, your controller runs on a lower voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is a 24v controller, you should still be able to use it. Provide the power input with a 24vac supply. Then, cut an extension cord in half. Rejoin the neutral and earth wires, and connect the live wires to the C and NO connections (or NC if you want to invert the behaviour of the load.

There's no rule saying the load needs to be on the same power supply as the controller.